# Is there a single word for the ceiling of a cave or cavern?

Tags: single-word-requests

As the title says, I can't seem to find a word for the ceiling or the roof of a cave. I have searched and the correct term seems to be ceiling.

I want to know the word out of curiosity mostly, I assumed there might be a scientific term which would be concise. I would probably use it in a story to describe something on the ceiling of a cave, and I think it would be nice and concise to reduce 4 words to a single word.

Comment: I've retagged this correctly: please review the [tag info](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) and include details of how you intend to use the word, and why *ceiling* and *roof* are not suitable.

Comment: If you want to *describe* it and not simply *denote* it you need to understand that cave ceilings have a wide variety of characteristics, from smooth and level to being covered with stalactites to having soaring crevices.

Answer (score 6):

According to [ScienceViews.com](http://scienceviews.com/geology/cavefeatures.html), the correct term is **ceiling**.

Comment: And the National Park Service of the US agrees. https://www.nature.nps.gov/geology/usgsnps/cave/cave.html

Comment: Bats on the ceiling of Altar Cave: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Altar_Cave_-_bats_on_the_ceiling_of_the_main_chamber_(San_Salvador_Island,_Bahamas)_2_(15772039233).jpg

Comment: Yes to *ceiling*, sometimes also referred to as a *vault* when it resembles a dome.