# Word for a hole in the ceiling of a cave?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've already come up with the term 'shaft', but that's a rather long and narrow opening it seems.

Visualise a cave with an opening in the ceiling that lets rays of light through.

What would you call such a hole?

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299889/is-there-a-single-word-for-the-ceiling-of-a-cave-or-cavern

Comment: @SIRISHKUMARREDDY that's asking about the roof, rather than a hole in the roof.

Comment: You call it a hole.

Comment: An oculus is a circular hole in a dome (or other architectural surface).  The term can be borrowed to name a similar naturally occurring formation.

Comment: See also "chimney" or "vent".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are commonly referred to as a **skylight**

eg Skylight Cave in the USA:  http://ohdgrotto.caves.org/culture/photo-galleries/category/2-skylight-caves

also the Sanmenhai cave in China - from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanmenhai "The cave is unique in that it features seven skylights that mimic the layout of the constellation Ursa Major..."

They are most commonly found in the type of cave called a "lava tube", which is a sort of tunnel left behind by flowing lava, since they tend to have a relatively thin ceiling.

Comment: "Skylight" is a good specific answer given the description, but I do picture a ceiling "window".  A more general word (for small holes etc.) might be aperture.  In meaning, it is often understood to open to light.